# Facebook Graph API - overall_star_rating and rating_count Fields Not Populating in v2.10

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'd like to get the `overall_star_rating` and `rating_count` fields for the Facebook pages for several companies. The [Facebook Pages docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) show that this information should be available, yet I can't get fields to populate.

Example:

Querying information for a local company, Utah Projectors.

Facebook Page: https://www.facebook.com/utahprojectors/

Facebook Page ID: 152868571589318

Overal Star Rating: 4.8

Rating Count: 13

When I go to the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and query use the query string `152868571589318?fields=name,overall_star_rating,about,rating_count` I get the following response:

```
{
  "name": "Utah Projectors",
  "about": "We provide the best projectors around with the best service possible, all while keeping it local and personal.",
  "rating_count": 0,
  "id": "152868571589318"
}
```

You'll notice that the `overall_star_rating` isn't even included in the results (even though I requested it), and the `rating_count` doesn't show the correct number of ratings (which should be 13). I've tried changing my access token to just about everything I can think of - Using the Graph API Explorer tokens, using my Facebook App tokens (User Access Token, App Token, Page Access Tokens), and just about every combination I can think of. Clearly, I'm missing something.

What's even more curious is that I swear I was able to successfully query this information not more than a couple weeks ago! But I can't seem to get anywhere today. Please help! Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to give some further information, the issue is also existing using an older API version like 2.8, which worked great a few weeks ago. Unless there is no note regarding the rating in the Graph API change log, I assume it's a real bug in the Graph API. - I'd be lucky and thankful too, if anyone has further information!

Comment: Facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: There is currently an open Facebook bug report. This isn't the first time I've found a legit (significant) bug with Facebook... Anyway, here is the link to the bug Facebook thread: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1816620328365587/

Comment: Hi there! This should be fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a legit bug on Facebook's end, but it looks like they have fixed it. Details can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1816620328365587/